# Ejabberd module can't be found

Tags: ejabberd

```
-module(mod_mess_filter).
-behaviour(gen_mod).
%% Required by ?INFO_MSG macros
-include("logger.hrl").
   
%% Required by ?T macro
-include("translate.hrl").
-include_lib("xmpp/include/xmpp.hrl").
%% gen_mod API callbacks
-export([start/2, stop/1, depends/2, mod_options/1, mod_doc/0]).
-export([on_filter_packet/1]).
start(_Host, _Opts) ->
   ?INFO_MSG("Hello, my filter plugin!", []),
   ejabberd_hooks:add(filter_packet, global, ?MODULE, on_filter_packet, 0). 
on_filter_packet(Packet) -> 
   From = xmpp:get_from(Packet),
   To = xmpp:get_to(Packet),
   Type = xmpp:get_type(Packet),
   Content = post_request(From,To,Type,Packet),
   ?INFO_MSG("Mess : ~p", [Packet#message.body]),
   modify_packet(Packet, Content).
stop(_Host) ->
   ?INFO_MSG("Bye bye, ejabberd world!", []),
   ok.
depends(_Host, _Opts) ->
  [].
mod_options(_Host) ->
  [].
mod_doc() ->
   #{desc =>
         ?T("This is an example module.")}.
start_httpc() ->
 application:start(inets).
post_request(From, To, Type, Packet)
 when (Type == chat) orelse (Type == groupchat) ->
   BodyText = xmpp:get_text(Packet#message.body),
       ?INFO_MSG("From : ~p", [From]),
       ?INFO_MSG("To : ~p", [To]),
       ?INFO_MSG("Type : ~p", [Type]),
       ?INFO_MSG("BodyText : ~p", [BodyText]),
 start_httpc(),
 Options = [],
 Url = "https://123.249.79.79/xyapp/service/mess/filter",
 Headers = [
  {"Content-Type", "application/json"}
],
 UnicodeContent = BodyText,
 UnicodeFrom = jid:encode(From),
 UnicodeTo = jid:encode(To),
 Body = "{" 
           ++ "\"from\":" ++ "\"" ++ binary_to_list(UnicodeFrom) ++ "\","
           ++ "\"content\":" ++ "\"" ++ binary_to_list(UnicodeContent) ++ "\","
           ++ "\"to\":" ++ "\"" ++ binary_to_list(UnicodeTo) ++ "\"" ++
         "}",
{ok, Response} = httpc:request(post, {Url, Headers, "application/json", Body},Options, []),
 case Response of
  {{_, 200, _}, _, RstBody} ->
     ?INFO_MSG("RstBody: ~p", [RstBody]),        
     RstBody;
  {error, _} ->
     BodyText
 end;
post_request(_From, _To, _Type, _Packet) ->
   ok.
modify_packet(Packet, Content) ->
   Packet#message{body = [#text{data = Content}]}.
```

Is my path :

root@debianPT001:~/.ejabberd-modules/sources/mod_mess_filter/src# ls

mod_mess_filter.erl

root@debianPT001:~/.ejabberd-modules/sources/mod_mess_filter/src# pwd
/root/.ejabberd-modules/sources/mod_mess_filter/src

root@debianPT001:~/.ejabberd-modules/sources/mod_mess_filter# ls
mod_mess_filter.spec  src

I hope to implement a module for filtering user chat content, which will put the processed string returned after my request into the packet for essay collection

I am currently performing the same operation as in the official document

But I found that ejabberctl couldn't find the plugins I configured into it

Answer (score 0):

> If my path : root/.ejabberd-modules/sources/mod_mess_filter/mod_mess_filter.erl

I guess you are following
https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/extending-ejabberd/modules/#add-your-module

First of all, something very important that isn't mentioned in that page:
do NOT run `ejabberdctl module_update_specs`, because that will delete the existing modules and your source code!

In step 2 you forgot that the `*.erl` file must be inside `src/` directory, it should be:
`root/.ejabberd-modules/sources/mod_mess_filter/src/mod_mess_filter.erl`

A trick to enable the module easily: add the file `root/.ejabberd-modules/sources/mod_mess_filter/conf/mod_mess_filter.yml` with this content:

```yaml
modules:
  mod_mess_filter: {}
```

Once you do those changes, you can install it with "ejabberdctl module_install mod_mess_filter", and the module will start, but it is not compatible with recent ejabberd versions. I try your source code with ejabberd 23.10 and crashes.

I've made minor changes to use xmpp library, filter only chat/groupchat messages, and send only the body text:

```erlang
-module(mod_mess_filter).

-behaviour(gen_mod).

%% Required by ?INFO_MSG macros
-include("logger.hrl").

%% Required by ?T macro
-include("translate.hrl").

-include_lib("xmpp/include/xmpp.hrl").

%% gen_mod API callbacks
-export([start/2, stop/1, depends/2, mod_options/1, mod_doc/0]).

-export([on_filter_packet/1]).

start(_Host, _Opts) ->
    ?INFO_MSG("Hello, my filter plugin!", []),
    ejabberd_hooks:add(filter_packet, global, ?MODULE, on_filter_packet, 0). 

on_filter_packet(Packet) -> 
    From = xmpp:get_from(Packet),
    To = xmpp:get_to(Packet),
    Type = xmpp:get_type(Packet),
    post_request(From,To,Type,Packet),
    Packet.

stop(_Host) ->
    ?INFO_MSG("Bye bye, ejabberd world!", []),
    ok.

depends(_Host, _Opts) ->
    [].

mod_options(_Host) ->
    [].

mod_doc() ->
    #{desc =>
          ?T("This is an example module.")}.

start_httpc() ->
  application:start(inets).

post_request(From, To, Type, Packet)
  when (Type == chat) orelse (Type == groupchat) ->
    BodyText = xmpp:get_text(Packet#message.body),
        ?INFO_MSG("From : ~p", [From]),
        ?INFO_MSG("To : ~p", [To]),
        ?INFO_MSG("Type : ~p", [Type]),
        ?INFO_MSG("BodyText : ~p", [BodyText]),
  start_httpc(),
  Options = [],
  Url = "http://123.249.79.79/xyapp/service/mess/filter",
  Headers = [
    {"Content-Type", "application/json"}
  ],
  UnicodeContent = BodyText,
  UnicodeFrom = jid:encode(From),
  UnicodeTo = jid:encode(To),
  Body = "{" 
            ++ "\"from\":" ++ "\"" ++ binary_to_list(UnicodeFrom) ++ "\","
            ++ "\"content\":" ++ "\"" ++ binary_to_list(UnicodeContent) ++ "\","
            ++ "\"to\":" ++ "\"" ++ binary_to_list(UnicodeTo) ++ "\"" ++
          "}",
  {ok, Response} = httpc:request(post, {Url, Headers, "application/json", Body},Options, []),
  case Response of
    {{_, 200, _}, _, RstBody} ->
      RstBody;
    {error, Cause} ->
      Cause
  end;
post_request(_From, _To, _Type, _Packet) ->
    ok.
```

Comment: I‘m sorry ,I typed wrong the *.erl path . now I'm already update my question . Actually, my path is correct
Can you help me take a look again?

Answer (score 0):

Does ejabberd store and read modules from the path `/root/.ejabberd-modules/`? Or maybe ejabberd is using a different path?

One method to know the path that ejabberd is using for those modules:

```
ejabberdctl debug
ext_mod:modules_dir().

"/home/badlop/.ejabberd-modules"
```

Another method is to run `ejabberdctl modules_update_specs`, and search in the `$HOME` of the user that runs ejabberd the directory `.ejabberd-modules`.

Comment: I I have successfully implemented message filtering using the improved plugin, but it seems to conflict with offline messages. When configuring this module, it seems that I cannot make my offline messages take effect.

Comment: Can you help me look my new answer? Thank you

Comment: I've tested with ejabberd 24.02 and my version of the module, and the messages are stored offline as usual, no matter if I enable or disable the module.

Did you make changes to the module? Most importantly, the `on_filter_packet` function must return `Packet` at the end, because that allows other modules (like mod_offline) to process the stanza too.

Did you check if the messages are stored offline in the database? For example, I can view this in the ejabberd WebAdmin, in my case it's in http://localhost:5280/admin/server/localhost/user/user123/

Comment: I My modifications to my code have been placed in the code block of the question I raised, but I returned a packet and it still cannot send offline messages. Can you try using my code locally in your localhost? it will success or fail ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your new module source code with ejabberd 24.02 and my Jabber client, and it produced some error messages.

I've fixed those errors, and now it works for me:

- when destination is online, the messages are sent correctly to him
- when destination is offline, messages are stored in the offline strage database
- when user becomes online again, the offline messages are sent to him
- if any message is modified by the HTTP service, the modified message is sent to the online user, or is stored offline and delivered when he logins.

Here is the updated source code:

```erlang
-module(mod_mess_filter).
-behaviour(gen_mod).
%% Required by ?INFO_MSG macros
-include("logger.hrl").
   
%% Required by ?T macro
-include("translate.hrl").
-include_lib("xmpp/include/xmpp.hrl").
%% gen_mod API callbacks
-export([start/2, stop/1, depends/2, mod_options/1, mod_doc/0]).
-export([on_filter_packet/1]).
start(_Host, _Opts) ->
   ?INFO_MSG("Hello, my filter plugin!", []),
   ejabberd_hooks:add(filter_packet, global, ?MODULE, on_filter_packet, 0). 
on_filter_packet(Packet) -> 
   From = xmpp:get_from(Packet),
   To = xmpp:get_to(Packet),
   Type = xmpp:get_type(Packet),
   post_request(From,To,Type,Packet).
stop(_Host) ->
   ?INFO_MSG("Bye bye, ejabberd world!", []),
   ok.
depends(_Host, _Opts) ->
  [].
mod_options(_Host) ->
  [].
mod_doc() ->
   #{desc =>
         ?T("This is an example module.")}.
start_httpc() ->
 application:start(inets).
post_request(From, To, Type, Packet)
 when (Type == chat) orelse (Type == groupchat) ->
   BodyText = xmpp:get_text(Packet#message.body),
       ?INFO_MSG("From : ~p", [From]),
       ?INFO_MSG("To : ~p", [To]),
       ?INFO_MSG("Type : ~p", [Type]),
       ?INFO_MSG("BodyText : ~p", [BodyText]),
 start_httpc(),
 Options = [],
 Url = "https://123.249.79.79/xyapp/service/mess/filter",
 Headers = [
  {"Content-Type", "application/json"}
],
 UnicodeContent = BodyText,
 UnicodeFrom = jid:encode(From),
 UnicodeTo = jid:encode(To),
 Body = "{" 
           ++ "\"from\":" ++ "\"" ++ binary_to_list(UnicodeFrom) ++ "\","
           ++ "\"content\":" ++ "\"" ++ binary_to_list(UnicodeContent) ++ "\","
           ++ "\"to\":" ++ "\"" ++ binary_to_list(UnicodeTo) ++ "\"" ++
         "}",
{ok, Response} = httpc:request(post, {Url, Headers, "application/json", Body},Options, []),
 Content = case Response of
  {{_, 200, _}, _, RstBody} ->
     ?INFO_MSG("RstBody: ~p", [RstBody]),        
     RstBody;
  {error, _} ->
     BodyText
 end,
 modify_packet(Packet, Content);
post_request(_From, _To, _Type, Packet) ->
   Packet.
modify_packet(Packet, Content) ->
   Packet#message{body = [#text{data = Content}]}.
```